# How to locate user on Unix command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

Below script can be executed as follows.

```
. ./ifcommand jaso3
```

If the user entered; in this case ***jaso3***, is logged in to the system. It is easy executing on the command line, but I would like to write a script for greater ease as follow.

```
#!/bin/sh

name=$1

check=$(who | grep -e '${name}' | cut -d' ' -f1)

if [${check} = ${1}]
  then
       echo "User found"
else
       echo "User not Found"
fi
```

When I attempt to run this code as stated above I get a blank line. I attempted a few troubleshooting steps inside the script to isolate just the line

```
check=$(who | grep -e '$1' | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

If I could get it to print, but I could not. I have suspicion that it has something to do with the "who" command. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `if  [${check} = ${1}]` is invalid: you need spaces on _both_ sides of `[`.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback. I have commented out this portion and tried to echo the check=$(who | grep -e '$1' | cut -d' ' -f1) just to see if anything would print, and I was returned a blank line. My question is why does this command not work?

Comment: Perhaps because you are single quoting the variable, and single quotes _disable_ variable expansion. IOW, you are literally grepping for the string `"$1"` rather than the contents of `$1`. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Genius! That did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has two issues. With respect to the `who` pipeline, your variable is single quoted - which disables variable interpolation. Thus the code greps for a literal `"$name"` instead of the value held in `$name`. Change to double quotes.

Also, your `if` statement needs white space around *both* sides of `[` - this is so because it is just a program (`test`) that expects arguments.